# PGFPlot presets in preamble to not show scientific numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I have a document that consists of a main file and multiple section.tex files that are included in the main file. The sections have figures and tables as separate tex.

The tables and figures come directly from my Python code, so I'm wondering if there is a way to change the PGFPlots axis style globally through the main file's preamble?

What I mean with scientific numbers is in this pic the y-axis

[image]

I'm hoping to change the default and skip the y and x-axis scientific numberings like here

[image]

These pics above are not from my code, but from another example.

Here is a minimum example of how my TABLE.tex file looks like, but I do not want to edit this file, because it comes directly from Python script.

```
% This file was created with tikzplotlib v0.10.1.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{darkslategray38}{RGB}{38,38,38}
\definecolor{lavender234234242}{RGB}{234,234,242}
\definecolor{steelblue31119180}{RGB}{31,119,180}

\begin{axis}[
axis background/.style={fill=lavender234234242},
axis line style={white},
tick align=outside,
x grid style={white},
xlabel=\textcolor{darkslategray38}{year},
xmajorgrids,
xmajorticks=false,
xmin=1914.85, xmax=2006.15,
xtick style={color=darkslategray38},
y grid style={white},
ylabel=\textcolor{darkslategray38}{pop},
ymajorgrids,
ymajorticks=false,
ymin=71097.9889446721, ymax=239041.908801229,
ytick style={color=darkslategray38}
]
\path [draw=steelblue31119180, fill=steelblue31119180, opacity=0.2]
(axis cs:1919,139896.179713115)
--(axis cs:1919,78731.8034836065)
--(axis cs:1925,84035.2299180328)
--cycle;

\addplot [semithick, steelblue31119180]
table {%
1919 104781.131147541
1925 114831.262295082

};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then have these section.tex files

```
\section{Working with the Data}

    In Figure \ref{fig:pop_g} we can observe the population growth for Germany during the sample period
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \input{figs/pop.tex}
        \centering
        \caption{Population Growth}
        \label{fig:pop_g}
    \end{figure}
```

And finally, I have this main.tex file which is used to run the whole show, where I would like to make the global setting.

```
%! Author = Rick Garmin
%! Date = 12.5.2023


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amscd, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}


%for plots
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm} % bigger plot
\pgfplotsset{tick label style={font=\tiny}, label style={font=\scriptsize}, legend style={font=\tiny}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{colortbl}


\usepackage{natbib}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\usepackage{pdflscape}




\listfiles

\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
\marginparwidth 40pt
\marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin -20pt
\headsep 10pt
\textheight 8.7in
\textwidth 6.65in
\linespread{1.2}

\title{Economics - Term Paper}
\author{Rick Garmin}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle


    \include{sections/q1}
    \include{sections/q2}




    %\bibliographystyle{apalike}
    %\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show MWE (Minimal Working Example) which produce the first showed image!